# How do i protect $.ajax datatype:json Post parameters

Tags: json, jquery

**I am using the parameters for updating via Web service method.
Please see the post below.**

```
Post: http://myweb.com:8241/web/Dashboard.aspx/BindDatatable
Host: localhost:8241
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: http://myweb.com:8241/web/Dashboard.aspx
Content-Length: 49
Cookie: .ASPXANONYMOUS=ltv9ZiqjzgEkAAAANGZlZTY2ODItYmFkMy00OWI5LWIxMDktNGU5NTg4M2IyOTVj2fU3SjopgaEx5DOYla827v7hFQNzpmfoFvRqDv1859g1; ASP.NET_SessionId=1bro3mtv1gbcqswhlced251h
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Send Post Content?

```
{stat: "201541",search:"",points:"100",delete:""}
```

**Is it possible to encrypt this post content? Or revise my code not to use json? I am just confuse about this, and i think i am about to build vulnerability here. Please help.**

Comment: Your content is not proper JSON. The keys need to be quoted. Use `JSON.stringify()`, don't try to roll your own JSON.

Answer (score 4):

Encrypt?  Sure, use HTTPS.

Protect?  Against what?  If you are concerned about someone posting whatever they want to your web service, or seeing how it works, there is nothing you can do to prevent that.  All you can do is not trust data from the user.

Comment: Thank you brad for helping me out about this. I was just having trouble with this parameters {stat: "201541",search:"",points:"100",delete:""} as it can be modified. What if someone mess with it, giving him an option to delete records by manipulating the delete parameter? like this {stat: "201541 and so on increment values",search:"",points:"100",delete:"1"}

Comment: @Mr.Adamant, Enforce user permissions server-side.  If a user shouldn't be able to delete something, don't let them delete something.

Comment: Hmmm that sounds good for me brad, but how will i be able to implement this in server side? do you have external source or link on how will i configure this method? This is web based. My bad i am just new in web dev that's why. I just dont want my pages to make some postbacks that's why i implemented json on my code.

Comment: @Mr.Adamant, There is no specific way I can help you, as I have no idea what your code does and how you check your sessions and do authentication/authorization.  At a high level, it is simple.  No matter if a user is using a web service with JSON, or posting from HTML forms, validate the user's session, make sure that they have permissions to modify any objects being modified, and reject the request or accept it.